# Setting up GTK# on Rider

Tags: c#, gtk#, rider

Has anyone had any luck setting up GTK# on Rider? Specifically on Sierra but I've had similar problems on Windows. Running

```
mcs -pkg:gtk-sharp-2.0 HelloWorld.cs
```

will compile just fine, but on Rider I can't seem to find any of the typical assemblies (gtk-sharp, glib, etc etc). How does one go about adding the reference properly?

Answer (score 0):

A workaround solution is to add references to the csproj file manually:

```
<Reference Include="gtk-sharp, Version=2.4.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=35e10195dab3c99f">
  <SpecificVersion>False</SpecificVersion>
</Reference>
<Reference Include="gdk-sharp, Version=2.4.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=35e10195dab3c99f">
  <SpecificVersion>False</SpecificVersion>
</Reference>
<Reference Include="glib-sharp, Version=2.4.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=35e10195dab3c99f">
  <SpecificVersion>False</SpecificVersion>
</Reference>
<Reference Include="glade-sharp, Version=2.4.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=35e10195dab3c99f">
  <SpecificVersion>False</SpecificVersion>
</Reference>
<Reference Include="pango-sharp, Version=2.4.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=35e10195dab3c99f">
  <SpecificVersion>False</SpecificVersion>
</Reference>
<Reference Include="atk-sharp, Version=2.4.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=35e10195dab3c99f">
  <SpecificVersion>False</SpecificVersion>
</Reference>
<Reference Include="Mono.Posix" />
```